# Probability and statistics expected value

Tags: expected-value

The number of car accidents during one week on a busy motorway is modelled by random variable $X$ with distribution $\mathbb P(X=k) = e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, where $\lambda=0.5$.

How can I solve how many car accidents are expected to happen in a week?

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for expected value: $E(X)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)k=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}k$